# Qt for Android debugging issues

Tags: android, qt, gdb, qt-creator

I have setup a kit in Qt Creator to deploy my applications to Android. Looked at https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Android_known_issues, and ended up with:

- Qt Creator 4.3.1
- Qt 5.9.1
- NDK: r10e
- SDK: r25.2.5

I deploy to a tablet running Android 5.1.1.

"Run" Works fine. My applications is deployed, started, and crashes hard. Therefor I'd like to debug, but that does not go so well. Before my app even starts I get the error "Connecting to remote server failed:
Attaching to process 6285 failed"

ADB logcat:

`I/Qt      ( 5981): qt start
D/houdini ( 5981): [5981] Added shared library /data/data/org.qtproject.example.gui/qt-reserved-files/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so for ClassLoader by Native Bridge.
D/houdini ( 5981): [5981] Added shared library /data/data/org.qtproject.example.gui/qt-reserved-files/plugins/position/libqtposition_android.so for ClassLoader by Native Bridge.
I/QtPositioning( 5981): Positioning start
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: extra parameters: Bundle[{debug_ping=true, gdbserver_socket=/data/data/org.qtproject.example.gui/debug-socket, qml_debug=true, gdbserver_command=/data/data/org.qtproject.example.gui/lib/libgdbserver.so --multi +/data/data/org.qtproject.example.gui/debug-socket, qmljsdebugger=port:38509,block,services:DebugMessages,QmlDebugger,V8Debugger,QmlInspector, ping_socket=org.qtproject.example.gui.ping_pong_socket}]
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: removing gdb socket /data/data/org.qtproject.example.gui/debug-socket
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: starting /data/data/org.qtproject.example.gui/lib/libgdbserver.so --multi +/data/data/org.qtproject.example.gui/debug-socket
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: gdbserver started
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: waiting for socket at /data/data/org.qtproject.example.gui/debug-socket, attempt 0
W/libgdbserver.so( 6001): type=1400 audit(0.0:13): avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="personality-8" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: waiting for socket at /data/data/org.qtproject.example.gui/debug-socket, attempt 1
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: socket ok
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: Debug socket accepted
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 5981): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
D/AndroidRuntime( 6008): >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 6008): CheckJNI is OFF
W/art     ( 6008): Could not create mount namespace.
W/        ( 6008): Failed to bind-mount /system/lib/x86/cpuinfo as /proc/cpuinfo: Operation not permitted
E/        ( 6008): Cannot create code cache directory ./code_cache: Read-only file system.
I/Build   ( 6008): Restore serial number.
D/AndroidRuntime( 6008): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
I/ActivityManager( 2911): Force stopping org.qtproject.example.gui appid=10080 user=0: from pid 6008
I/ActivityManager( 2911): Killing 5981:org.qtproject.example.gui/u0a80 (adj 0): stop org.qtproject.example.gui
I/libprocessgroup( 2911): Killing pid 6001 in uid 10080 as part of process group 5981
D/ActivityManager( 2911): cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 5981
I/ActivityManager( 2911):   Force finishing activity 3 ActivityRecord{1325d u0 org.qtproject.example.gui/org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity t20}
W/ActivityManager( 2911): Spurious death for ProcessRecord{90e0893 5981:org.qtproject.example.gui/u0a80}, curProc for 5981: null`

Comment: it's hard to tell, please share more info, JDK-Ant maybe some code. does your App work on your os ?

Comment: It works on my OS, and with Run it starts on Android as well. With Debug it seems to crash when setting up the debugger.

Comment: I suggest you to make textEdit and append text in it from different place in your App, like qDebug.

Comment: Got hold of a Shield Tablet running Android 7 and my app works fine there, both for Run and Debug, so perhaps it has to do with the Android version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
get the installation folder for your app:

```
adb shell run-as <package name of your app> /system/bin/sh -c pwd
```

then change the file attributes on that folder:

```
adb shell run-as <package name of your app> chmod "a+x"  <output of previous command>
```

You can get your package name from the android manifest file. After that, debugging from Qt Creator should work fine - or it did for me.